# How to detect mouse is now over child element and not its parent , when they have same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `jquery` to find currently hovered element. my html is like this:

```
<div class="parent myclass">
    parent
    <div class="child myclass">
        child
    </div>    
</div>
```

Now i want insert border on currently hovered element with class `myclass` .
But when mouse is over child element `jquery` not detects that mouse is not over the parent.

Maybe it is asked before but i don't know how to search about it.
and here is a fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/uxa38xjz/1/

How i can change that code, so if mouse is over the child, only child element receive class `.hovered`. currently when mouse is over child script not removes `.hovered` from parent.

**edit:**

This is my script:

```
$('.myclass').mouseover( 
function(){ 
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
} )
.mouseout(
    function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

And this is the `css` :

```
.parent{
width: 100px;
height:100px;
display:block;
background-color:#eee;
margin:80px;
}

.child{
width: 70px;
height:70px;
display:block;
background-color:#00f;
}

.hovered{
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00; 
}
```

**edit2:**
Only thing that i know is that this elements has class `myclass`. and i don't know what is the element names or what classes they have.

Thanks.

Comment: Put the relevant code **in** your question, not just linked (not even jsfiddle). People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Also note that SO has its own Stack Snippets now.

Comment: Can you use `$('.parent .myclass')` to refer child div and `$('.myclass .child')` for parent div?

Comment: No, that parent and child are sample classes for styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are getting is because of event bubbling, whenever an event is triggered in the child element it is caried to the top level. Try by adding `return false;` like below,

```js
$('.myclass').mouseover( 
    function(){ 
        $(this).addClass('hovered');
        return false;
    } )
    .mouseout(
        function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
```

```css
.parent{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#eee;
    margin:80px;
}

.child{
    width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#00f;
}

.hovered{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent myclass">
    parent
    <div class="child myclass">
        child
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the particular element at the mouse position using [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) method as shown below:

```js
$('.myclass').mouseover(function(e) {
  var elm = document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY);
  $(elm).addClass('hovered');
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 80px;
}
.child {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #00f;
}
.hovered {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent myclass">parent
  <div class="child myclass">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice but it is buggy in my browser . i think returning false is better !

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `is(':hover')` method to achieve this:

```js
$('.myclass').mouseover( 
    function(){
        if($('.child').is(":hover")) {
            $('.parent').removeClass('hovered');
            $('.child').addClass('hovered');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('hovered');
        }
    } )
    .mouseout(
        function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hovered');
    });
```

```css
.parent{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#eee;
    margin:80px;
}

.child{
    width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#00f;
}

.hovered{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px #f00; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent myclass">
    parent
    <div class="child myclass">
        child
    </div>    
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uxa38xjz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `child` class on the child elements, so a pure CSS solution would be:

```
.child.myclass:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

...or to add a `hovered` class, but you really don't need it for modern browsers (or even IE8):

```
$(".child.myclass").hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass("hovered"); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass("hovered"); }
});
```

If that `child` class isn't really there (you were just adding it to clarify your question), I'd add it, either when writing the HTML or, if unavoidable, adding it via JavaScript on page load. Either way, I'd use CSS for the actual hover effect.

Here's an example of adding that class via JavaScript (and the CSS hover effect):

```js
$(".myclass").filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents(".myclass").length > 0;
}).addClass("child");
```

```css
.child.myclass:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
    parent
    <div class="myclass">
        child
    </div>    
</div>
```

And here's an example using a `hovered` class instead:

```js
$(".myclass").filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents(".myclass").length > 0;
}).hover(
  function() { $(this).addClass("hovered"); },
  function() { $(this).removeClass("hovered"); }
);
```

```css
.hovered {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
    parent
    <div class="myclass">
        child
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the mouseover-part:

```
function(events){ 
      var that=$(events.currentTarget);
      if(that.attr('class').match('child')){
         $(this).addClass('hovered');
      }
})
```

Now just change the "match" to whatever you like (parent/child) ;).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`$("div > p"`)  All p elements that are a direct child of a div element

or

```
:has(selector)  $("div:has(p)") 

All div elements that have a p element
```

customize according to your need. I hope you have been routed